# android 4.0 toast.cancel() don't work well

Tags: android

In my app,I want to cancel the old toast ,and show the new toast.But it dont work well .

```
                             Handler postHandler = new Handler();     
                        postHandler.post(new Runnable() {  
                            @Override  
                            public void run() {  

                                    if (toast != null) {  
                                        toast.cancel();
                                toast.maketext(this,"new toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);



                                    } 
                                    toast.show();  

                            }  
                        });  


                return false;
            }
        });
```

but  nothing  shown .

The logcat shows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at android.view.View.onAttachedToWindow(View.java:9533)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:9786)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2198)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:957)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2453)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6706):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  183):   Force finishing activity com.rk.youming/.Testsurfacevie
```

Comment: Are you sure this error throws from your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes no real sense. You reference new toast and try to `cancel()` it before it is shown. If you wanted to `cancel()` you have to call it on object referencing old toast, not new one. If toast is `null` you won't cancel() it (because of `if`) but still attempt to `show()` which will end in NPE anyway.

Comment: thank you.I want to show toast when clicking button and shown in different position.So I want to cancel the old toast and show the new one.

Comment: Toasts are queued, so unless you are really need to cancel old one, just show new one and that's it.